# Send Email with data (ASP.NET mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

I need to make sending Email by button click.

I make Model for Email

```
public class MailModel
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public bool IsShowAlert { get; set; }
}
```

And make method in Controller like this

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Index(Models.MailModel _objModelMail)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.To.Add(_objModelMail.To);
                mail.From = new MailAddress(_objModelMail.From);
                mail.Subject = _objModelMail.Subject;
                string Body = _objModelMail.Body;
                mail.Body = Body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
                ("suhomlin.eugene95@gmail.com", "dontoretto23");// Enter seders User name and password
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(mail);

                return View("Index", (IEnumerable<Clients>) _objModelMail);
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

All work's when I create new view for Email.

But I need to do this not in new view.

Here is my View design
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfASO.png)

Here is code of View

```
  @model IEnumerable<SmartSolutions.Models.Clients>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml";
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Список клиентов";
}





<table class="table">
    @{int rowNo = 0;}



    <tr style="background: #d1d3d4">
        <th></th>
        <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th >
        <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </th>
        <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Position)
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 40px; width: 40px; background: red;">
            <a href='@Url.Action("Create", "Clients")'>
                <img style="object-fit: cover;" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/plus.png")' />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        <tr >
            <td class="point">
                @(rowNo += 1)
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Position)
            </td>

            <td style="text-align: end;">


                @Html.ActionLink("Отправить приглашение", "Details", new {id = item.ID}, new {@class = "sendinviteclass"})


                <a href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Clients", new {id = item.ID})'>
                    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Edit.png")'/>
                </a>
                <!-- @Html.ActionLink("Редактировать", "Edit", new {id = item.ID}, new {@class = "editclass"})-->
                <a href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Clients", new {id = item.ID})'>
                    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Delete.png")'/>
                </a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

When I click to marked button, I need  to send email to adress that is on EMAIL column with default text.

Marked button is button in table.

Default text is smth like "You added to system go to testwebsite.com. Your password is `PasswordField` in database."

Here is Clients model

```
 public class Clients
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Ф.И.О")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Должность")]
    public string Position { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Пароль")]
    public string Password { get; set; }


}
```

How I can do this?

Comment: post your view here

Comment: I hope you did not just post your e-mail credentials.

Comment: ahaha, no of course @Juan

Comment: Updated my post @teovankot

Comment: I don't see a `<FORM>` element nor do I see any buttons.  I do see a few links.  If you're trying to send any user input to the server, you need a form with a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Models are meant to pass data back and forth from the UI. In this case, you are not really collecting information from the user. You already have it.

There are a couple of ways you could do this. What I would personally recommend is that you have an action that takes an id, pulls out the user information and creates the e-mail:

```
public ActionResult SendEmail(int id)
{
     //Retrieve the user data and create e-mail here.
     return RedirectToAction("Index","YourController");
}
```

Notice the redirect at the end to send the user back to the view that triggered the e-mail send.

Then in your view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Send E-mail", "SendEmail", new {id = item.ID})
```

This is an over-simplified version and you should consider certain things like security and posts but I think you get the idea... :-)

Comment: As I understood I need to have SendEmail View, but I want to send Email directly from this view

Comment: @E.S: Negative. Once you send the e-mail, simply redirect the user to the action you were on before (presumably "Index").

Comment: I am updating my answer to account for the redirect I mentioned.